# Shopify Deployment on Ubuntu VM

Tags: node.js, reactjs, deployment, shopify, shopify-api-node

I am trying to setup the Shopify App on the Ubuntu VM - I have configured the Nginx for the Public URL but once I run the command npm run dev then I get the link for authorization and once I copy paste the link in the browser I get the http://127.0.0.1:3456/?c with the error like site can not be reach.

I have tried changing the port no in nginx.conf but still not able to solve the problem
I was expecting to connect with Shopify

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please provide steps of deployment you followed for better support.